# prevent scope watch on reload page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my simple directive :

```
app.directive('someButton',function(){
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    template : "<button>{{buttonText}}</button>",
    link : function(scope,element,attr){
        scope.$watch('counter',function(oldVal,newVal){
            console.log("counter changed from ",oldVal ,"to " ,newVal);

        })

    }
}
```

});

the value that been changed is a counter in the scope,that initialized like this:

$scope.counter = 0 ;

I also got button that on click does counter++;

When my page reloads, the console says that "changed from 0 to 0".how can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because you are not persisting your `$scope.counter` and hence after page refresh your `$scope.counter` will be reset to 0. As a result, in the watch you will get new and old value both as 0. If you want to persist you can use localStorage (or sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `oldVal` to the `newVal`, and if they are the same, return:

```
scope.$watch('counter',function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal === oldVal) {
        return;
    }

    console.log("counter changed from ",oldVal ,"to " ,newVal);
});
```